# How can I dispaly ngx-quill rich text editor data from database to a page for view mode

Tags: angular, ngx-quill

I have angular project and I have used ngx-quill rich text editor, it works perfect when add new records or edit records and it stores the result in database.
now I want to display the result from rich text to a component it display like this:

```
<p>And this is some text<strong> this is another text</strong></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code will do it for you:)

```
<div [innerHTML]="yourContent"></div>
```

for more info: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#!#other-bindings

Comment: Happy to helped you